# Символы вопроса вместо текста при открытии файла html

Tags: python, requests

Вот код:

```
import requests
request = requests.get('https://vk.com')
sitehtml = open('vk.com.html','w')
request.encoding = 'utf-8'
r = request.text
sitehtml.write(r)
print(request.text)
```

Сам код файла html отображается нормально, но когда открываешь его в каком либо браузере, вместо текста появляются знаки вопроса.
[image: Отображение в браузере]

[image: Код самого файла]

Comment: Причем насколько я понял, такое происходит только с текстом на русском языке.

Comment: Попробуйте указать параметр `encoding`: `open('vk.com.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да, сработало. Спасибо. А тут можно указывать комментарии в качестве решения?

Comment: Рад помочь :) Увы, но комментарии нельзя отмечать как верные (только "плюсовать"). Я опубликовал решение в форму ответа, вот его отметить можно (нажав на зелёную галочку слева от него).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажите параметр `encoding`.

***Пример:***

```py
sitehtml = open('vk.com.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```